# joining a 2d list side by side

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to join two, 2d, list side by side.  However I am having trouble, this is what I have so far

```
def join_map_side(map1, map2):
ans = []

    if len(map1) != len(map2):
        return None
    if len(map1) == len(map2):
       for check in range(len(map1)):
            if len(map1) == len(map2):
                ans = [[].append(x) for x in list(zip(map1,map2))]


return ans
print(join_map_side([[1,2],[5,6]], [[3,4],[7,8]]))
```

this returns [5, 6, 7, 8] but i want it to return [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]].
can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `zip`. I'll leave out the size checks to keep it simple.

```
ans = [u + v for u, v in zip(map1, map2)]
```

---

Here's a more complete version, wrapped in a function, just in case you do need that size check. But if you can guarantee that the input lists are the same length, or you don't mind losing the trailing sublists from the longer one, I recommend the simpler version.

```
def join_map_side(map1, map2):
    if len(map1) == len(map2):
        return [u + v for u, v in zip(map1, map2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straight one -

```
def join_map_side(map1, map2):
    ans = []
    if len(map1) == len(map2):
        for index in range(0,len(map1)):
            ans.append(map1[index] + map2[index])
    return ans

print(join_map_side([[1,2],[5,6]], [[3,4],[7,8]]))
```

@PM 2Ring - that `zip` approach is smart. It seems I need to learn more of python.

Comment: Thanks. Generally in Python it's better to iterate directly over the items of a list, rather than doing it indirectly with indices. It makes the code both cleaner, and more efficient. And if you do need the index as well, you can use `enumerate` to get the index and the item, rather than using `range`. Sometimes, it does make sense to loop with `range`, but not often.